# How to print SOAP XML response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am using below system properties:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
                System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
                System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
                System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
```

This is printing:

```
---[HTTP response - https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/v1.0?wsdl - 200]---

null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Language: en-US

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 12:23:42 GMT

Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><sch:InquiryResponse xmlns:sch="http://XXXXXXXXXX/1.0"><sch:InquiryResponseHeader><sch:ClientID>XXXX</sch:ClientID><sch:ProductCode>PCS</sch:ProductCode><sch:SuccessCode>0</sch:SuccessCode><sch:Date>XX-XX-XXXX</sch:Date><sch:Time>17:53:28</sch:Time></sch:InquiryResponseHeader><sch:InquiryRequestInfo><sch:InquiryPurpose>05</sch:InquiryPurpose><sch:FirstName>Ajay</sch:FirstName><sch:LastName>XXXX</sch:LastName><sch:AddrLine1>XXXX</sch:AddrLine1><sch:State>MH</sch:State><sch:Postal>411014</sch:Postal><sch:DOB>1987-06-21</sch:DOB><sch:Id>XXXX</sch:Id><sch:MobilePhone>XXXX</sch:MobilePhone></sch:InquiryRequestInfo><sch:ReportData><sch:Error><sch:ErrorCode>E0021</sch:ErrorCode><sch:ErrorMsg>User ID does not exist for the given customer.</sch:ErrorMsg></sch:Error></sch:ReportData></sch:InquiryResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I get XML data from above printing data?

I want to store that XML in a variable for further use.

Thanks.

Comment: You might not be able to do that directly with any built in stuff as you'll get the Request information back. A workaround to this would be to separate it out first and then parse it accordingly to get a new clean XML response without the headers or if you want to use a different methodology, try JAX-WS

Answer (score 0):

MessageHandler:

Utilizing the extensible Handler framework provided by JAX-WS Specification and the better Message abstraction in RI, we introduced a new handler called MessageHandler to extend your Web Service applications. MessageHandler is similar to SOAPHandler, except that implementations of it gets access to MessageHandlerContext (an extension of MessageContext). Through MessageHandlerContext one can access the Message and process it using the Message API. As I put in the title of the blog, this handler lets you work on Message, which provides efficient ways to access/process the message not just a DOM based message. The programming model of the handlers is same and the Message handlers can be mixed with standard Logical and SOAP handlers. I have added a sample in JAX-WS RI 2.1.3 showing the use of MessageHandler to log messages and here is a snippet from the sample:

```
        public class LoggingHandler implements MessageHandler<MessageHandlerContext> {
public boolean handleMessage(MessageHandlerContext mhc) {
    Message m = mhc.getMessage().copy();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLStreamWriterFactory.create(System.out);
    try {
        m.writeTo(writer);
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean handleFault(MessageHandlerContext mhc) {
    ..... 
    return true;
}

public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {    }

public Set getHeaders() {
    return null;
}
```

}